# How to change the histogram colour in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, histogram

So i'm awful at Matlab and I mainly learn through examples and literally spelt out explanations.
So baring that in mind - Right now i'm trying to find how likely it is that one image i'm given is in anther via a histogram.

What i want to do is create 3 histograms for red, blue & green for each image and then add those into one image - So basically i'll have an image with a literal green histogram showing the green, a red one showing the red and a blue one showing the blue.

I know that to show a colour chanel in matlab i have to do imhist(image(:,:,1/2/3)
however that still gives me a histogram in blue.

I've looked up some things that are meant to help with this issue but it's normally aimed toward someone who knows what they're doing.... not helpful.
I've heard peope saying something like get(get(gca,'child')) which just seems giberish to me.

SO - for what i'm trying to do, image detection via histrograms, is this an appropriate method? And if so HOW do i create my 1 histogram that shows all 3 histograms in their respective colour

Cheers

Comment: I've seen this in several places:
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','w')

if this is the easiest way to do it, can someone please explain it?
i've no idea what it's do and whats what

Just read a little further ahead an apparently that code doesn't work for imhist

Comment: This is kind of a hack. `findobj` in your case tries to find all graphics objects in the current axes of type "patch". These are the low-level graphics-objects matlab uses. This does not work if `imhist` does not use patches, but e.g. lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this version of imhist:

```
[counts,x] = imhist(...)
```

And then draw your histograms yourself, via `bar`, `stem` or similar.
These functions are then fully customizable and you can plug in your favourite color, linestyle, etc.

Comment: Cheers, however my friend told me that if i created a simple 
imhist with each of the colour channels and then made ANOTHER hist by doing like t1hist = [t1r, t1g, t1b];